# Adding external photos to iPhone library in correct order

Tags: itunes, photos, iphone, macos

The last 3 years I've been making photos on my iPhones which have now turned into a nice collection on my phone. I love looking at those photos as they are all sorted by date, which is nice to scroll back into time.

Now I've also had another portable cam those years, which has made some nice pictures which I've got stored on my computer.

**What I would like to achieve is:** Add those photos which I've made on another none Apple devices to my library on my iPhone. And have them show up around the dates that they were taking in the library on the iPhone.

So external pics taken in Dec 2012 should show up together with iPhone pictures taken around those dates in my iPhone library.

I currently have an iPhone 5 and the latest iTunes on my Windows computer. How could I achieve this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Non tested manual method

1. create a new folder ALL_PHOTOS on your PC/Mac
2. copy all your iphone photos directly to ALL_PHOTOS
3. copy all your camera photos directly to ALL_PHOTOS (no subfolders)
4. go to iTunes, select your iDevice, go to Photos section, check 'Sync Photos' checkbox and **choose the ALL_PHOTOS folder as your 'copy photos from' folder**.
5. Sync

After sync done, all your photos should appear as a new album in Photos app. Then you can safely delete photos from Camera album on your iPhone. Repeat this procedure once in a while.

Downsides:
1. 100% manual, slow and boring procedure
2. an annoying problem with duplicate filenames can arise